# Magento 2 Categories not showing in Admin Product Edit Page

Tags: magento2

we have a problem with Magento 2.1.14 enterprise where selected categories for any product and category tree is not displaying randomly. IF I refresh the cache , it start showing up again . we are using Fastly cache.